# Could you reuse the IV for AES256-GCM as salt for HKDF-SHA256?

Tags: key-derivation

I am having a 32 byte shared secret from a KEM , I want to use AES-GCM for encrypting messages in this process random iv has to be created , can I use this iv as salt for hkdf-sha256 to generate more keys, will this be secure? I will create 2 keys one for AES-GCM and another for HMAC-256

Comment: You could randomly generate a salt and use that with HKDF to derive the keys plus an IV. Also, the salt should go in the `info` parameter because HKDF is weird, as explained [here](https://soatok.blog/2021/11/17/understanding-hkdf/comment-page-1/). Not a fan of HKDF.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a shared secret, which, I assume is bound to a session over multiple messages.

It now depends if you want to create additional keys for each message. If that's the case then you can indeed use the IV + a key identifier, and as mentioned in the comments, I'd put those in the Info field using a canonical representation (simple concatenation for statically sized fields). However, it is a bit of a strange way of handling keys if that's the case, having a session key to encrypt messages, and a separate set of keys for each one individually.

If you need more keys per session then you don't need the per-message IV of course, you can just use $\operatorname{KDF}(S, KeyID)$ where S is the shared secret and KeyID specifies the specific key / key type.

Note that an attacker can usually disturb an IV value, and that the IV is only protected in AES-GCM after you've verified the authentication tag. That means that a derived key may be altered by an adversary, which is why you should try and avoid these kind of schemes. Otherwise you may not know which part of the protocol was disturbed.